# I cannot seem to access values stored in the position 0 and 1 of array

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview

For some reason, the array in my code can provide values stored in other positions but not in position 0 and 1, this array is inside a for loop and I'm just fetching images from the internet and appending to the array, but when I load these images into a collection view, all other cells but cell 0 and 1 display images with their index paths corresponding to the positions of the array, It shows in the array count that the total number of count in the array is the expected amount but then, it just won't get values stored in those positions.

```
class correctHomeViewController: UIViewController {
   
    public var imgarrPic : [UIImage] = []
    var imgarr = ["https://www.unsplash.com/photos/_3Q3tsJ01nc/download?force=true","https://www.unsplash.com/photos/dlxLGIy-2VU/download?force=true","https://www.unsplash.com/photos/TPUGbQmyVwE/download?force=true","https://unsplash.com/photos/9MRRM_hV4qA/download?force=true","https://unsplash.com/photos/HbAddptme1Q/download?force=true","https://unsplash.com/photos/wSct4rrBPWc/download?force=true","https://unsplash.com/photos/PKMvkg7vnUo/download?force=true"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadImage()
    }

    func loadImage() 
    {    
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
        config.allowsCellularAccess = true
        config.waitsForConnectivity = true

        let sesh = URLSession(configuration: config)
        
        for position in 0..<imgarr.count {
            
            let url2 = URL(string: imgarr[position])
            
            let data = sesh.dataTask(with: url2!) {data, _, error in
                if data != nil && error == nil {
                    let data3 = data!
                    let image = UIImage(data: data3)!
                    self.imgarrPic.append(image)
                } else {
                    if error != nil || data == nil {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.view.showToast(toastMessage: error!.localizedDescription, duration: 5)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            data.resume()
        }
    }
}

//displaying in the collection view
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "productCell2", for: indexPath) as! ProductsViewCell
        
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.cornerRadius()

        if self.imgarrPic.count == self.imgarr.count {
            cell.productImage.image = self.imgarrPic[indexPath.item]    
        } else {
            cell.productImage.image = UIImage(named: "pwPic")
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of an asychronous process?

Comment: Is it still an asynchronous process if it NEVER updates itself? Even after 15 minutes with stable internet?

Comment: Yes.  You can set a `timeoutInterval` value to `URLSession`.

Comment: I put an indicator in my code to show how many items were fetched into the array after the for loop has been completed which urlsession doesn’t go past, and it shows the amount I was expecting, my point is, I don’t think URLsession sits idle at some point as it fetches the images completely, I just can’t access images at position 0 and 1, it’s like they don’t exist which is strange because positions 2 and 3 and so on displays fine